# How to check null hypothesis that two random symbols generators are the same?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data

I have two random "distributions" that generate "symbols" or "classes" instead of numbers. Different symbols have different probabilities to be generated. I want to check the null hypothesis that the two distributions are identical.

For example the first distribution has generated:

```
A, A, B, A, A, A, B, A, C, A, A
```

and the second distribution has generated:

```
C, A, B, C, B, C, C, C
```

I want to know if there is a reason to believe that the distributions are different.

In my case the number of observations is not identical. For example I might have a lot of observations for the first distribution and not so much for the second one.

Answer (score 3):

Tabulate the symbols generated in a two-way table and run [Pearson's $\chi^2$ test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test).